# Simplify java regex code to validate passwords

Tags: java, regex, passwords

I want to inform the user what he needs so that his password is valid, when it does not meet the requirements the `jlabels` changes color RED and when it meets it changes to Black. The shortest way that I could do what I want, but it will exist other? I attach the code and a photo

```
    private void JB_MostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    String password = "";

    password = jPasswordField_pass.getText().trim();

    final String regex = "^(?:(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=.,]).*)[^\\s]{8,}$";

    if (password.equals("")) {
        jl_Error.setText("Please enter your Password.");
        jl_Error.setForeground(Color.red);

    } else if (password.matches(regex) == false) {

        jLabel_infopass.setText("Your password must be between 8 and 64 characters long. It must contain at least three (3) of the below:");
        jLabel_infopass.setForeground(Color.red);

        if (Pattern.matches("(?=.*\\d).*", password) == false) {
            jLabel_infopass3.setText("numbers (0-9)");
            jLabel_infopass3.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            jLabel_infopass3.setText("numbers (0-9)");
            jLabel_infopass3.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
        if (Pattern.matches("(?=.*[a-z]).*", password) == false) {
            jLabel_infopass2.setText("lowercase (a-z)");
            jLabel_infopass2.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            jLabel_infopass2.setText("lowercase (a-z)");
            jLabel_infopass2.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
        if (Pattern.matches("(?=.*[A-Z]).*", password) == false) {
            jLabel_infopass1.setText("uppercase (A-Z)");
            jLabel_infopass1.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            jLabel_infopass1.setText("uppercase (A-Z)");
            jLabel_infopass1.setForeground(Color.black);
        }
        if (Pattern.matches("(?=.*[@#$%^&+!.,]).*", password) == false) {
            jLabel_infopass4.setText("symbols (e.g. #, $, !, @, ^, &, *, etc)");
            jLabel_infopass4.setForeground(Color.red);
        } else {
            jLabel_infopass4.setText("symbols (e.g. #, $, !, @, ^, &, *, etc)");
            jLabel_infopass4.setForeground(Color.black);
        }

    } else {
        jLabel_infopass.setText("Your password must be between 8 and 64 characters long. It must contain at least three (3) of the below:");
        jLabel_infopass.setForeground(Color.black);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, password);
    }
}
```

[image: capture run box]

Comment: Get rid of the four displays and just tell him the rules in one. Then just use a single regex that either matches or it doesn't. This is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a simple line to inform the user about the password restrictions. A single line with "Your password must be 8-64 characters in length with at least three of number or special characters"
2. Use Pattern class to validate your password.

   ```
   import java.util.regex.*;  

   // this will check for 8-64 character with at least 3 numbers or special characters
   String passwordRegex = "(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,64}[\d#$@!%&*?]{3,}";

   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(passwordRegex);

   // this is inside your password check function
   Matcher match = pattern.matcher(passwordCheck);

   if(match.matches()){
   // OK
   } else {
   // show warning message
   }
   ```